# Mathematics function animation

Tags: animation

I am trying to animate a 2d parabola I created with Z math surface. Is there a way to animate the parabola without scripting?

Or is the best way to use animation nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Geometry nodes solution**

I just animated the factor.

[image]

[image]

**Next GN solution**

Here I animated A and B value.

[image]

result:

[image]

***Classic solution with hooks***

In Edit mode, select all vertices and press <kbd>CTRL-H</kbd> to create a hook modifier. Change the radius until you like the result. Then you can animate the empty-location and/or the radius.

[image]

[image]

Comment: And where's geometry nodes solution? :)

Comment: ok....sorry....coming...

Comment: updated my answer :D

Comment: Great, since you're in it, now add two input values (constants) `a` and `b`, and make the particle's `z` equal `x*x/(a*a) + y*y/(b*b)`, then animate a and b with a driver 

Comment: i am not that rich. I have no driver. I drive myself 

Comment: oh man...don't know why i did this....

Comment: Very nice!!! 

Comment: _ditto_, please consider elevating nodes answer to top spot.  Re hook: Be an interesting problem for the mathematicians to construct the equation of new parabola formed by hooks translation.  Off to test Inverse square falloff.

Comment: @batFINGER: done